# Issue with executing subreport in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have two reports:

Main Report (displayed as a list)

ISGN,... are the columns from table1

Subreport ( displayed as a table)

ISGN,.... are the columns from table2

### Requirement:

1. The Main Report should be diplayed in one page (one isgn per page)
2. The subreport should be displayed in the next page (this should take the isgn from the main report as the parameter)

### My Approach:

1. In the design, I have put each of the column  in the main report in a different text box
2. All these text boxes are in one single rectangle
3. I have inserted the subreport in main report's  rectangle
4. I have two different data sets filling the main report and the subreport
5. For the Subreport I have created a parameter prmisgn
6. In the design view, i have right clicked on my subreport--> subreport properties-->Parameters-->prmisgn=isgn from the main report
7. For the data set which fills my subreport, i have applied a filter as isgn=prmisgn

### Issue:

When i preview this report, I get an error:

`An error occured while executing the sub report. An object reference is not referring to an instance of an object`

Could you please help me out with this? thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/70503/business-intelligence?referrer=EPHSm8-3avvaMxLjdRIeNg2

Comment: Does the sub-report work on its own?

Comment: How is the dataset "filling the main report"? You cant assign a dataset to a rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the Rectangle in the Main report with a Table, and assign it to the table1 Dataset.  Table layout is quite flexible, you can have multiple rows and columns with groups.  One cell (probably on the Details row) will contain the subreport.

Answer (score 0):

Since your subreport has parameters, you should pass value from the main report to the subreport for the parameter,  Steps are:

```
In Design view, right-click the subreport and then click Subreport Properties.

In the Subreport Properties dialog box, click Parameters.

Click Add. A new row is added to the parameter grid.

In the Name text box, type the name of a parameter in the subreport. This name must match a report parameter in the subreport. If the subreport is in the project, you can choose the parameter from the drop-down list. If the subreport is on the report server, run the report in Report Manager, and on the Properties tab, click Parameters.

In the Value list box, type or select a value to pass to the subreport. This value can be static text or an expression pointing to a field or other object in the main report.

Repeat steps 3-4 to specify a value for each subreport parameter.
```